# Not able to fix syntactical error in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert data from a staging table into original table for a particular time period in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 using below query.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.trial ([turbineid], [createddate], [lastupdatedby],[lastupdateddate])
    SELECT 
        [turbineid], [createddate], [lastupdatedby], [lastupdateddate] 
    FROM 
        dbo.trial_January
    WHERE
        createddate BETWEEN (DATEPART(mm, createddate) = 01 
                             AND DATEPART(dd, createddate) = 01))
                        AND (DATEPART(mm, createddate) = 01 
                             AND DATEPART(dd, createddate) = 30)
```

When trying to execute this query, I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: In a table whose name contains the word "January", why do you need to use any month-based logic as a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a date with some integers.
Your where clause should look more like this

```
WHERE createddate BETWEEN (DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YY,createddate),1,1)) AND (DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YY,createddate),1,30))
```

Answer (score 0):

your where condition is not correct

```
 where DATEPART(mm , createddate) = 1
```

gives you results for first month.  you dont need to have anything else for the day if your intention is to look for whole january

Comment: `DATEPART(mm)` returns an **INT** - so your check should **not** include any unnecessary single quotes - just `DATEPART(MONTH, createdDate) = 01`

Answer (score 0):

This claus doesn't make sense

```
 where  createddate between 
 (DATEPART(mm , createddate) = 01 AND DATEPART(dd, createddate) = 01))
  AND (DATEPART(mm, createddate) = 01 AND DATEPART(dd, createddate) = 30)
```

Between state needs two date to check if the given date is between two dates.

for exemple :

```
SELECT 'true' WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN GETDATE() -1 AND GETDATE() + 1
```

And the DATEPART(mm, CreatedDate) returns the month of your date.

```
SELECT 'true' where  DATEPART(mm , GETDATE()) = 10 //Checks if the month of the given date is 10.
```

According your query, you want to get records of january. So you can try this

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.trial ([turbineid], [createddate], [lastupdatedby],[lastupdateddate])
SELECT 
    [turbineid], [createddate], [lastupdatedby], [lastupdateddate] 
FROM 
    dbo.trial_January
WHERE
   DATEPART(MONTH, createddate) = 01 
   AND DATEPART(YEAR, createddate) = 2020 -- the year you want
```